# Python build dataframe from multiple separate variables

Tags: python, dataframe

I am a Python novice and came across a doubt that haven't yet found solution for, despite more likely to be very easy to sort.

I have 2 variables and a Pandas dataframe, say:

```
A = 1
B = "c_10"
df = pd.DataFrame({"column_1": [1] , "column_2": [2] , "column_3": [3] })
```

My objective is to have a dataframe that looks like column A | B | df - see the type below - ie all columns together.

For example, column "A" will have value 1, column "B" would have value "c_10" and then columns "column_1" "column_2" and "column_3" would have values 1 to 3.

I have tried to use some of the functions like merge or concatenate but couldn't get through the correct solution.

```
A = 1
B = "c_10"
df = pd.DataFrame({"column_1": [1] , "column_2": [2] , "column_3": [3] })

pd.merge(str(it),t , df)
```

I keep getting errors due to merging a dataframe with class str or int.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is equal to add new columns to existed `DataFrame`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column_1": [1] , "column_2": [2] , "column_3": [3] })
A = 1
B = "c_10"
df.insert(0,'A',A)
df.insert(1,'B',B)
print(df.to_string(index= False))
```

Output is

```
A     B  column_1  column_2  column_3
1  c_10         1         2         3
```